# Get current month and previous month as column names in Impala query?

Tags: sql, dynamic, impala

I am trying to build a dynamic query that generate reports for the past 4 months from Impala.

I have tried this:

```
SET MONTH1 = MONTHNAME(NOW());
SET MONTH2 = MONTHNAME(MONTHS_ADD(NOW(),-1));

Select item, Sum(val1) as ${MONTH1}, sum(val2) as ${MONTH2} FROM MyTable
Group by item;
```

But it didn’t work. Any ideas?

Comment: SQL doesn't natively support dynamically named columns.  It requires running code to find the columns names, then writing new SQL with those column names and then separately executing that programmatically generated SQL *(termed 'dynamic-sql')*.  Checking on-line, impala doesn't support that pattern *( https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Impala-Dynamic-SQL/td-p/41129 )*, instead just call the columns `this_month` and `previous_month`, then write your reporting/application layer to implement any column renaming prior to presentation for human consumption.

Comment: I noticed that. But I have seen such practice previously on oracle where variables are declared and then used as column names.

Comment: Yes, as I described.  When the code runs it generates the new column names, then embeds those column names in a new SQL string, and then executes that new SQL string *(and that is termed 'dynamic-sql')*.  That's code that writes and executes new code.  But, as I stated and linked, ***Impala does not support that pattern***; impala simply doesn't have a way to take string and execute it as a SQL Statement.  Just because Oracle (and other dialects) can do that, doesn't mean impala can.